# GeoServer Callback Function Undefinded

Tags: geoserver, leaflet

Any idea why the function loadThis() comes back as undefined?
I've tried adding jsonp: false  which doesn't help either. The json object is returned properly, I can view it in FireBug, but I can't get it to the callback function. Hope it's something simple I've missed,

```
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON();

function loadThis(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

$.ajax({
    url : "http://geoserver.capecodgis.com/geoserver/capecodgis/ows?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=capecodgis:tracts_2010_4326&maxFeatures=2&outputFormat=json&format_options=callback:loadThis",
    dataType : 'jsonp'
});

map.addLayer(geojsonLayer);
```

Comment: This is the site I'm testing with:  http://leaflettest.capecodgis.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Things to change to make this work:

- use jsonpCallback in your $.ajax call to provide the name of callback function
- use success to specify a function to handle your data once it is retrieved
- note that the callback name and the name of the function used to process your data need to be different

Here's working code:

```
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON();

function handleJson(data) {
  console.log(data)
  geojsonLayer.addData(data); 
}

$.ajax({
  url : "http://geoserver.capecodgis.com/geoserver/capecodgis/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=capecodgis:tracts_2010_4326&maxFeatures=2&outputFormat=json&format_options=callback:getJson",
  dataType : 'jsonp',
  jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
  success: handleJson
});

map.addLayer(geojsonLayer);
```

Comment: Wow, nice. Thank you so much. I've been agonizing over this for 2 days.

Comment: Glad I could help!