# How to retrieve the attributes of the clicked line or polygon feature in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, getfeature

In GeoServer, I'd like to retrieve the attributes of a feature that is clicked by the user. When the feature is a point, I can simply use the bounding box parameter of a WFS [GetFeature method](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html) to get the point.

I do not know how to do when the feature is a line or polygon. Any ideas? An example would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some reading to do. Here's a start. [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) and  [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/).
You probably want to focus on GeoJson format for now.

Leaflet is a bit easier to get up and running. My opinion anyways. Here's a [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48522/geoserver-callback-function-undefinded) I posted with a great answer for connecting to GeoServer.

In addition here's a [great example](http://projects.bryanmcbride.com/leaflet/geojson_hacks.html#) for guidance by Bryan McBride who seems to know how to do everything.

Comment: just to clarify, that was a compliment to Bryan McBride. He really is most helpful with things GIS